# How to write unit test case using XCTest/XCTest.h "xcode 5.1" for UIWebView

Tags: cordova, uiwebview, xcode5, xctest

I am trying to do a test case for UIwebview but `<XCTest/XCTest.h>` is not showing the load above. It's showing only a blank white screen.

How should I use it?

Comment: Can you share the code? What you have done so far?